# How to install Plotly (Using Anacando or PIP) from work computer

Tags: python, installation, pip, plotly

Please help. I am using Anaconda for Python coding.  I am using a work computer so have my firewalls etc. I would like to download Plotly, but get many errors.

Anaconda Navigator: from Environment I have searched for Plotly, but it is not there (installed or not installed)

PIP: I have been to the command prompt and typed: **pip install plotly**
I get this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plotly

PIP TRY 2: **pip install plotly==4.14.3**
Then I get the error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly==4.14.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plotly==4.14.3

PIP TRY 3: **pip install --upgrade pip**

I also tried conda in the command prompt but got errors saying 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Thanks

Comment: If you are seeing errors like `ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool`, while running pip install then you are behind proxy, you could try running pip install command after setting proxy. 
`export https_proxy=http://proxy.domain.com` or `pip install --proxy http://proxy.domain.com install <package>`

Answer (score 1):

In the **Anaconda Prompt** use this command:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

I think it should work.